# Regex Pattern help: finding HTML pattern when nested ASP.NET Eval?

Tags: html, asp.net, regex

http://regexr.com/3cgju

```
Pattern = ((<\/?[\w\s="/.':;#-\/]+>)|(<\%@[\s\S]+\"\s%>))
```

When using this as a testing syntax:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<td class="c1 c2 c3" colspan="2">
lorem ipsum
<div class="d1" id="div2" attrid="<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>">
testing 123
</div>
asdf
</td>
```

and this is the same as above just added line numbers, so I can more easily ask my question:

```
1. <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
2. <td class="c1 c2 c3" colspan="2">
3. lorem ipsum
4. <div class="d1" id="div2" attrid="<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>">
5. testing 123
6. </div>
7. asdf
8. </td>
```

That RegEx pattern correctly matches lines 1, 2, 6, and 8, but only partially matches line 4:
It only matches this part of line 4:

```
<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>
```

But I want it to match the entire line of line 4:

```
<div class="d1" id="div2" attrid="<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>">
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for **PCRE**:

```
<(([^<>]|(?R))*)>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tE8nJ1/2

---

And this for **.NET**:

```
(?'o'<)(.*)(?'-o'>)+
```

Demo: [link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%27o%27%3c)(.*)(%3f%27-o%27%3e)%2b&i=%3c%25%40+Page+Language%3d%22C%23%22+%25%3e%0d%0a%3ctd+class%3d%22c1+c2+c3%22+colspan%3d%222%22%3e%0d%0alorem+ipsum%0d%0a%3cdiv+class%3d%22d1%22+id%3d%22div2%22+attrid%3d%22%3c%25%23+Eval(%22CategoryID%22)+%25%3e%22%3e%0d%0atesting+123%0d%0a%3c%2fdiv%3e%0d%0aasdf%0d%0a%3c%2ftd%3e)

Or:

```
(?'o'<)([^<>]*)(?'-o'>)+
```

to restrict capturing group, if you don't use newlines between lines.

Comment: When I try to copy/paste your Regex into http://regexr.com/3cgju , it finds no matches.

Comment: It's about regex flavor. Let me check.

Comment: *"RegExr uses your browser's RegExp engine for matching, and its syntax highlighting and documentation reflect the JavaScript RegExp standard."* The site you are using uses browser's regex. That's the reason. Which programming language will you use this regex on?

Comment: When trying to use that RegEx pattern in C# , the code: `MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, "<((?:[^<>]|(?R))*)>")` gives the error: `System.ArgumentException : parsing (regex statement) Unrecognized grouping construct`

Comment: Seems like the ?R is the problem for some reason

Comment: So, you want .NET regex, OK. Original was PCRE, please wait a bit and let me modify it.

Comment: It seems .NET don't have recursive patterns, so we can't use ?R. I'm going to try something else.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to open a new question about why the .NET answer doesn't work in C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563469/regex-works-on-net-test-site-but-not-in-c-sharp-environment