# Regex works on .NET test site but not in C# environment

Tags: c#, regex

Referring to this stackoverflow question:
- [Regex Pattern help: finding HTML pattern when nested ASP.NET Eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562041/regex-pattern-help-finding-html-pattern-when-nested-asp-net-eval/)

I received an answer to the problem here:
- [regexstorm link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%27o%27%3C%29%28.*%29%28%3F%27-o%27%3E%29%2B&i=%3C%25%40%20Page%20Language%3D%22C%23%22%20%25%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%20class%3D%22c1%20c2%20c3%22%20colspan%3D%222%22%3E%0D%0Alorem%20ipsum%0D%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22d1%22%20id%3D%22div2%22%20attrid%3D%22%3C%25%23%20Eval%28%22CategoryID%22%29%20%25%3E%22%3E%0D%0Atesting%20123%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0Aasdf%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E)

The .NET answer that works on the regex .NET testing site does NOT work in my C# Visual Studio environment. Here is the Unit Test for it:

```
[Test]
public void GetAllHtmlSubsectionsWorksAsExpected()
{
    var regPattern = new Regex(@"(?'o'<)(.*)(?'-o'>)+");

    var html = 
        "<%@ Page Language=\"C#\" %>" +
        "<td class=\"c1 c2 c3\" colspan=\"2\">" + 
        "lorem ipsum" + 
        "<div class=\"d1\" id=\"div2\" attrid=\"<%# Eval(\"CategoryID\") %>\">" + 
        "testing 123" + 
        "</div>" + 
        "asdf" + 
        "</td>";

    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    MatchCollection matches = regPattern.Matches(html);
    for (int mnum = 0; mnum < matches.Count; mnum++)
    {   
        Match match = matches[mnum];
        results.Add("Match #" + (mnum + 1) + " - Value: " + match.Value);
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(5, results.Count()); //Fails: results.Count() == 1
}
```

Why does this work on the regexstorm website but not in my unit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE that parsing HTML with regex is not a best practice, you should use a dedicated parser.**

Now, as for the question itself, the pattern you use will work only with *lines* having 1 single substring starting with `<` and ending with corresponding `>`. However, **your input string has no newline characters!** It looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %><td class="c1 c2 c3" colspan="2">lorem ipsum<div class="d1" id="div2" attrid="<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>">testing 123</div>asdf</td>
```

The `.*` subpattern is called a *greedy dot matching* pattern, and it matches as many characters other than a newline as possible (because it *grabs the whole line* and then *backtracks* to see if the next subpattern (here, `>`) is found, thus you get the last possible `>`).

To fix that, you need a proper balanced construct matching pattern:

```
<((?>[^<>]+|<(?<c>)|>(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))>
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C((%3F%3E%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D%2B%7C%3C(%3F%3Cc%3E)%7C%3E(%3F%3C-c%3E))*(%3F(c)(%3F!)))%3E&i=%3C%25%40%20Page%20Language%3D%22C%23%22%20%25%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22c1%20c2%20c3%22%20colspan%3D%222%22%3Elorem%20ipsum%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22d1%22%20id%3D%22div2%22%20attrid%3D%22%3C%25%23%20Eval(%22CategoryID%22)%20%25%3E%22%3Etesting%20123%3C%2Fdiv%3Easdf%3C%2Ftd%3E)

C#:

```
var r = new Regex(@"
    <                      # First '<'
      (                    # Capturing group 1
        (?>                # Atomic group start 
        [^<>]              # Match all characters other than `<` or `>`
        |
         < (?<c>)          # Match '<', and add a capture into group 'c'
        |
         > (?<-c>)         # Match '>', and delete 1 value from capture stack
        )*
        (?(c)(?!))         # Fails if 'c' stack isn't empty!
      )                
    >                      # Last closing `>`
"; RegexOptions.IgnoreWhitespace);
```

**DISCLAIMER**: Even this regex will fail if you have unpaired `<` or `>` in your element nodes, that is why *do not use regex to parse HTML*.

Comment: Are you sure that .* needs to be changed? I couldn't find an example to show the difference. As (?'o'<) part captures balanced groups, dot would not match < anyway. (With new lines of course, original question was with new lines)

Comment: And what's the difference with (?'o'<)([^<>]*)(?'-o'>) and <((?>[^<>]+|<(?<c>)|>(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))> ? It seems they are having the same effect.

Comment: I am sure that `.*` is not the best construct to use with delimited text. The [`(?'o'<)([^<>]*)(?'-o'>)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%27o%27%3c)(%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*)(%3f%27-o%27%3e)&i=%3c%25%40+Page+Language%3d%22C%23%22+%25%3e%3ctd+class%3d%22c1+c2+c3%22+colspan%3d%222%22%3elorem+ipsum%3cdiv+class%3d%22d1%22+id%3d%22div2%22+attrid%3d%22%3c%25%23+Eval(%22CategoryID%22)+%25%3e%22%3etesting+123%3c%2fdiv%3easdf%3c%2ftd%3e) will not match balanced substrings inside angle brackets. My last regex will match balanced `<...>` substrings correctly.

Comment: Can you please give an example to the balanced <...> substrings? I think my regex is matching too.

Comment: I made my answer more straight-forward. [Your regex does not match separate element nodes on one single line](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%27o%27%3c)(.*)(%3f%27-o%27%3e)%2b&i=%3cdiv+class%3d%22d1%22+id%3d%22div2%22+attrid%3d%22%3c%25%23+Eval(%22CategoryID%22)+%25%3e%22%3etest%3cmore%3e%3c%2fmore%3e%0d%0a). My regex does that, see my demo link. See [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2005/03/15/net-regular-expressions-regex-and-balanced-matching-ryan-byington/), too. Proper balanced construct matching must include the check for the stack state with a conditional clause.

Comment: Alright, it was quite a good explanation. I learned something new today. +1

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things in regex: Matching and capturing.

What you want here is the capturing group 1.

So you need to use this:

```
results.Add("Match #" + (mnum + 1) + " - Value: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Also, as the other answer pointed, you are missing new lines, and regex captures it all in first match.